# Validators for combobox in Vaadin

Tags: java, validation, combobox, vaadin

In text fields I can check how many characters entered by the user, for example:

```
Field field;
field.addValidator(
    new StringLengthValidator(
        "WARNING MESSAGE HERE", 6, 20, false));
```

If the number is not within the range, then warning message is throw. For numeric fields I can check the type:

```
field.addValidator(new Validator() {

   public boolean isValid(Object value) {
      try {
        float f = Float.parseFloat((String) value);
        return true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         field.getWindow().showNotification("WARNING MESSAGE HERE");
         field.setValue(0);                            
         return false;
      }
   }

   public void validate(Object value)
      throws InvalidValueException {
   }

});
```

For the combobox I specify the following:

```
final ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox("...");

if("someProperty".equals(propertyId)) {
   field = combobox;
}

field.setRequired(true);                
field.setRequiredError("WARNING MESSAGE HERE");
```

If I leave it blank, then no warning displayed and form sent to the server. What validator needed for ComboBox?

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Comment: To make things clear: your ComboBox is not validated right after value change, instead after commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the immediate callback to the server after the user changes anything.

```
// Fire value changes immediately when the field loses focus
combobox.setImmediate(true);
```

For that users don't have to wait to get a validation until they commit or do anything else what needs to interact with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should explicitly call validate() method:

```java
/**
 * Checks the validity of the Validatable by validating the field with all
 * attached validators except when the field is empty. An empty field is
 * invalid if it is required and valid otherwise.
 * 
 * The "required" validation is a built-in validation feature. If the field
 * is required, but empty, validation will throw an EmptyValueException with
 * the error message set with setRequiredError().
 * 
 * @see com.vaadin.data.Validatable#validate()
 */
public void validate() throws Validator.InvalidValueException {

    if (isEmpty()) {
        if (isRequired()) {
            throw new Validator.EmptyValueException(requiredError);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    // If there is no validator, there can not be any errors
    if (validators == null) {
        return;
    }
...
```

By default Form performs validation:

```java
/**
 * Checks the validity of the validatable.
 * 
 * @see com.vaadin.data.Validatable#validate()
 */
@Override
public void validate() throws InvalidValueException {
    super.validate();
    for (final Iterator<Object> i = propertyIds.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        (fields.get(i.next())).validate();
    }
}
```